# How to extract an elementary video stream from Avigilon .ave container?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec, h.264

I would like to figure out how to extract a H.264 video stream from an Avigilon `.ave` custom container. Unlike with [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Extracting_MPEG-4_Elementary_Stream_from_MP4_Container) where they are using ffmpeg to extract the elementary video stream, when I try to do it with ffmpeg it responds: `moov atom not found error` which probably means that the container/format has put the moov atom in location ffmpeg can't find it.

It is a non-standard container (Avigilon). I do not want to do this through their own media player.

I'm not sure how/where to go from here. I've used [MediaInfo](https://www.videohelp.com/software/MediaInfo) and managed to extract some information about the file, but I don't know how to use that information to acquire the elementary stream.

In the end of the day, I want to get the H.264 file from the container and use it directly. Any suggestions on how to approach this would be helpful.

MediaInfo for the file:

```
General
Count                                    : 331
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Complete name                            : /folder
Folder name                              : /folder
File name extension                      : file.ave
File name                                : filename
File extension                           : ave
Format                                   : ave2
Format                                   : ave2
Commercial name                          : ave2
Codec ID                                 : ave2
Codec ID                                 : ave2 (0x060E0212/0x0000BE6C)
CodecID_Compatible                       : 0x060E0212/0x0000BE6C
File size                                : 6330774432
File size                                : 5.90 GiB
File size                                : 6 GiB
File size                                : 5.9 GiB
File size                                : 5.90 GiB
File size                                : 5.896 GiB
Stream size                              : 6330774432
Stream size                              : 5.90 GiB (100%)
Stream size                              : 6 GiB
Stream size                              : 5.9 GiB
Stream size                              : 5.90 GiB
Stream size                              : 5.896 GiB
Stream size                              : 5.90 GiB (100%)
Proportion of this stream                : 1.00000
File last modification date              : UTC 2019-10-09 08:30:27
File last modification date (local)      : 2019-10-09 14:00:27
```

And an example of some log around it:

```
000000000 avfs (24 bytes)
000000000  Header (8 bytes)
000000000   Size:                                 24 (0x00000018)
000000004   Name:                                 avfs
000000008  Unknown:                               (16 bytes)
000000018 File Type (24 bytes)
000000018  Header (8 bytes)
000000018   Size:                                 24 (0x00000018)
00000001C   Name:                                 ftyp
000000020  MajorBrand:                            ave2
000000024  MajorBrandVersion:                     0 (0x00000000)
000000028  CompatibleBrand:
00000002C  CompatibleBrand:
000000030 ----------------------------
000000030 ---   MPEG-4, accepted   ---
000000030 ----------------------------
000000030 expc (524 bytes)
000000030  Header (8 bytes)
000000030   Size:                                 524 (0x0000020C)
000000034   Name:                                 expc
000000038  Unknown:                               (516 bytes)
00000023C datp (2317649 bytes)
00000023C  Header (8 bytes)
00000023C   Size:                                 2317649 (0x00235D51)
000000240   Name:                                 datp
000000244  Unknown:                               (2317641 bytes)
000235F8D rcfc (6794 bytes)
000235F8D  Header (8 bytes)
000235F8D   Size:                                 6794 (0x00001A8A)
000235F91   Name:                                 rcfc
000235F95  Unknown:                               (6786 bytes)
```

Comment: If the video container is truly custom, there's probably no way to extract information from it other than reverse engineering it, and adding code to ffmpeg to deal with it. If it's not custom, but a modification of existing container formats, it may be a lot easier. Your question hints that this may be the case (apparently MediaInfo gets some valid information), but it's utterly lacking any details, so there's nothing to base an answer to this question on. Only you have those details, we don't.

Comment: Share full log of your attempt. Also, share the file, if you can.

Comment: To specify a little more directly: it's of type Avigilon Native Video Export Filehttps://fileinfo.com/extension/ave

Comment: Does this help? https://spreadys.wordpress.com/2015/10/21/avigilon-ave-files/

Comment: I just updated with some log information. I am also going to clarify the question. I do not want to go through their media player. I am looking to do it directly on the file

Comment: The post question has been updated to reflect the boundary condition better,

Comment: Then you probably won't find a solution. These formats are proprietary and they deliver their own player for a (business) reason. There may be other reasons such as frame verification.

Comment: that makes sense. the issue is i need to transcode a high volume of them and so doing it through their player is not efficient.

Comment: The file appears to contain a single stream, so there's no interleaving involved. In such cases, it's possible to extract the raw bitstream using dd or even ffmpeg. However, since this is a security product's file, there may still be packet encapsulation or other interstitial data added.

Comment: i will look into this.

Comment: Would it be possible to post a sample ave file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have anything I can send over. I looked across the net and couldn't find something either. I'll send something if I find it